# Can the cause of the accelerating expansion of the universe be the very nature of the big bang?

Tags: dark-energy

Since the universe is expanding in all directions at once, like a loaf of bread dough rising, wouldn't all points further away from any refernce point simply appear to be accelerating? If so, then there is no need for a Dark Energy cause to explain this apparent, but misrepresented "acceleration".

Comment: No.  Dark energy is the cause of this acceleration. "all points further away from any refernce point simply appear to be accelerating? "  This is true though.

Comment: The current theory supports that there is dark energy

Comment: "Dark energy" is just bunk to explain why the current theories don't match observation - the "cosmological constant" in a modern guise.

Answer (score 3):

No. You need to distinguish between "moving away" (which all points would be) and "accelerating" (i.e. the "moving away" is getting *faster* over time). Having a Big Bang implies the first- that the universe is expanding over time, but *not* the second, that the expansion is getting faster.

Answer (score 0):

By “expansion” one means $\dot{a}>0$, where $a(t)$ is the scale factor of the universe. By “accelerating expansion” one means $\ddot{a}>0$. The former does not imply the latter (take, for example $a\propto t^{2/3}$, which is the rate of expansion in a matter dominated universe.)